# XpoweredBy not working in Web logic

Tags: java, apache, weblogic-10.x

I have used weblogic server 10.3. have to hide the X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1 from header response for that
i did the following

```
In weblogic admin console, under domainName->Configuration->Web Application, I set 'X-Powered-By Header ' to "X-Powered-By Header will not be sent".
```

It's working fine in local. but not working in server side.even though i cleared temp files and restart the server many times.

I tried by adding the following in web.xml also

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In php.ini locate the line containing “expose_php On” and set it to Off:

```
expose_php = Off
```

similarly how we hide that in java web application.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have an apache server with module header, you can try :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>  
  Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>
```

As describe in http://www.shanison.com/2012/07/05/unset-apache-response-header-protect-your-server-information/