# How do I remove certain HTTP headers added by Spring's RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm having a problem with a remote service I have no control over responding with HTTP 400 response to my requests sent using Spring's RestTemplate. Requests sent using `curl` get accepted though, so I compared them with those sent through RestTemplate. In particular, Spring requests have headers `Connection`, `Content-Type`, and `Content-Length` which `curl` requests don't. How do I configure Spring not to add those?

Comment: This answer might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339576/remove-http-response-headers-in-java

Comment: What error/response code are you getting? 401 Unauthorized?

Answer (score 5):

Chances are that's not actually the problem. My guess is that you haven't specified the correct message converter. But here is a technique to remove the headers so you can confirm that:

**1. Create a custom `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` implementation:**

```
public class CustomHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor
{

   @Override
   public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException
   {
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION);
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);

        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }

}
```

**2. Then add it to the RestTemplate's interceptor chain:**

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate()
{

   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   restTemplate.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new CustomHttpRequestInterceptor(), new LoggingRequestInterceptor()));

   return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Does not work properly. Only [setting headers to null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31021757) works.

Comment: You are creating a new object 'headers' and changes are never included in the request