# Bootstrap glyphicons briefcase not showing in IE Browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is html code for bootstrap icon, Bootstrap v3.3.4

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

this html code is working fine with all browsers, i can see briefcase icon properly. But with same code after developing in MVC Platfrom i can't see briefcase icon on IE and Safari (Windows). this problem with few other icon also like `content = "\e136"`, `content = "\e142"`

Developed Code in MVC:

[image]

Simple HTML Code

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm getting the same issue and the answers you've received have not been all that useful.  The issue for me occurs in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11, but not in Chrome or Firefox.  It seems to affect only the briefcase glyph.  I'm also using MVC, although I'm using bootstrap v3.3.2 for some reason (might try updating that).

Comment: Edit: glyphicon-alert also fails in the same way, although glyphicon-warning-sign works fine, so I'll probably use that instead... still no answer here though...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post will answer your question : [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9962)

adding

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Could solve your problem, by the way, which IE version are you using?

EDIT: then it could be IE security issue : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281286/bootstrap-3-2-0-glyphicons-are-not-displaying-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: try to modify your IE security settings, more informations here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281286/bootstrap-3-2-0-glyphicons-are-not-displaying-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: My IE browser "font download" security is already enabled. other icons are working but problem with few icons like "glyphicons briefcase", content = "\e136", content = "\e142" or

Answer (score 0):

You need to include

```
< !--[if lt IE 9] >
< script src="html5shiv.js">
< script src="respond.min.js">
< ![endif]-- >
```

Or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/css/glyphicons/glyphicons.min.css" >
```

OR

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Already Added.. working with others browsers problem with ie only

Comment: thanks.. but already added this meta tag. other icons are working properly, this problem with few icons not all.