# IE Bootstrap fonts (icons) not loaded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, ssl, load-balancing

Internet Explorer 11 has problems showing the icons of bootstrap. 
With Opera, Firefox and Chrome it works perfectly, and it also works with Edge but the icons are not shown with IE in Edge mode or (10,9,8).
Before I changed the website to https it worked all fine. I have this problem after changing it to ssl.

Does anyone know what I can do in order to solve this problem (at Server - Microsoft Azure or at load balancer)?

With IE (icons are not shown): 
[image: IE]

With Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Impossible to debug from the outside. Start by checking console for any messages about insecure resources being blocked or similar.

Comment: Is your website public? If yes, can we have the url to see it?

Comment: How are the settings in your InternetExplorer Security Settings?

Comment: have you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281286/bootstrap-3-2-0-glyphicons-are-not-displaying-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a problem with Security or Cache Settings -> check this thread for possible solution:

[bootstrap 3.2.0 glyphicons are not displaying in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281286/bootstrap-3-2-0-glyphicons-are-not-displaying-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Is there any possibility to make something on server?

Comment: You can try setting the headers like in this comment -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135282/font-face-wont-load-via-https-in-ie?rq=1#comment51628250_31622278 .

Answer (score 1):

Spring-Boot is generating cache-invalidating headers in HTTP responses:

```
Cache-Control :"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
```

and

```
pragma: "no-cache"
```

The solution is to hide those  headers to the browser.

I used nginx as a proxy, adding the folowing commands the https proxied location:

```
  proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
  proxy_hide_header Pragma;
```

See [here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093451/1767316) with nginx.

Using apache httpd, the syntax is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225692/1767316)