# All jsp pages are getting refreshed if refresh parameter is set at the first jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to refresh just the starting page (calling some functions) say **"1.jsp"** and as soon as the condition is fulfilled, it is redirected to another jsp page,say **"2.jsp"**, but not sure why the 2.jsp is also getting refreshed. Not only that, the function which was called in 1.jsp is also getting called.Below is sample code just for understanding:

**1.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <% 
    // Here i am trying to read some txt file which is contantly being updated. (by refreshing the page)
    // when txt file is written completely, some character like "### DONE ###" will be present at its last line.
    // once "### DONE ###" is found , it will be redirected to "2.jsp"


    System.out.println("1");
    // if "###DONE###" found
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("2.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);            

    %>
</body>
```

**2.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello World! PAGE 2</h1>
</body>
```

**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>1.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>SampleFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.SampleFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SampleFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/2.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

** SampleFilter**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response) {
    public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
        System.out.println(name+"-------------------------------");
        if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("Refresh")) {
            System.out.println("inside");
            super.setHeader("Refresh", "2");
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: You have to write more information

Comment: edited my code . Can you please look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you perform `rd.forward(request, response)` you actually forward the `response.addHeader("Refresh","2")` with it, causing the next page to refresh automatically as well.

I'm not sure why exactly you need the refresh before the forward, but if you must have it - check if you can remove the specific header ("Refresh"), maybe using the solution proposed here: [How do delete a HTTP response header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895196/how-do-delete-a-http-response-header)

**EDIT:**

Also, instead of triggering the refresh via server-side properties like the header, you should consider doing so via an HTML tag: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" />`

Comment: I have edited my code as per my understanding. Can you please guide me further. this thing is really imp for me. :(

Comment: (1) Remove the response.setHeader part from 2.jsp. (2) Change the url-pattern to "catch" 2.jsp instead of 1.jsp (3) In SampleFilter.java, replace !name.equalsIgnoreCase("tt") with !name.equalsIgnoreCase("Refresh") ---> this should tell the server to trigger the filter when 2.jsp is accessed, and to prevent the "Refresh" attribute from being applied to this 2.jsp page.

Comment: Thanks for such quick reply. i have edited my code,once again. The code which you have suggested is not refreshing "1.jsp". I have explained the reason for refreshing 1.jsp in the abv code. Please have a look at it

Comment: i tried creating another filter for "1.jsp" which does "super.setHeader("Refresh", "2");". but still "2.jsp" is getting refreshed

Comment: I'll try to check later the filter/header issue, but did you consider using Good-Old-HTML-Refresh: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" /> ?

Comment: Thanx!! above HTMP-Tag worked for me. will add this into my code, if it works will select this as an answer :)

Comment: Cool. I'll add it to the body of my answer, incase people google their way to this question :-)