# Springboot - Remove Content-Length header

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, servlet-filters, response-headers

In the spring boot (2.2.3 RELEASE) application, the 'Content-Length' header is not added explicitly but, present in every response.
There is now a requirement to add the 'Transfer-Encoding' header to the response. When it is added and the API is tested via Postman, it shows an error.
Console log:

> Error: Parse Error: Content-Length can't be present with
> Transfer-Encoding

Which was found to be in sync with [IETF HTTP 1.1 RFC7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) document.

Since the 'Content-Length' header is not required in the response API, it's filtered out using *@WebFilter* annotation.
*@Order* annotation is added with MAX Integer value to ensure that this filter is executed at the end.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class ContentLengthHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentLengthHeaderFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        LOGGER.info("filter init called !!!");
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOGGER.info("doFilter called ...............@@@");
        chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response) {

            @Override
            public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
                if (!HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equals(name)) {
                    LOGGER.info("adding header :" + name);
                    super.addHeader(name, value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
                if (!HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equals(name)) {
                    LOGGER.info("setting header :" + name);
                    super.setHeader(name, value);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        LOGGER.info("filter destroy called !!!");
        Filter.super.destroy();
    }
}
```

The logs shows that headers other than 'Content-Length' are added.

```
13.10.2022 11:25:34.947+0530 INFO  [o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Completed initialization in 8 ms
13.10.2022 11:25:34.959+0530 INFO  [a.b.c.d.ContentLengthHeaderFilter] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] doFilter called ...............@@@
13.10.2022 11:25:36.597+0530 INFO  [a.b.c.d.ContentLengthHeaderFilter] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] adding header :Location
13.10.2022 11:25:36.597+0530 INFO  [a.b.c.d.ContentLengthHeaderFilter] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] adding header :X-CustomHeader
13.10.2022 11:25:36.597+0530 INFO  [a.b.c.d.ContentLengthHeaderFilter] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] adding header :Transfer-Encoding
```

Still the API call results in 'Content-Length' header getting added to the response which causes the error mentioned above.
Am I messing any thing or is there any other way to remove 'Content-Length' header?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case of inverted cause and effect? Depends on what you want to achieve in regards to

> There is now a requirement to add the 'Transfer-Encoding' header to
> the response.

From the discussion over at this possibly related question (
[How to remove Content-length header from HTTP response generated in a simple server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317331/how-to-remove-content-length-header-from-http-response-generated-in-a-simple-ser)), we can see that there seems to be some special behaviour for the Content-Length header where it's always present unless explicitly set to 0 or -1. Which in turn should automatically lead to a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` on the response.

So as long as `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is what you want to achieve on your response, then I would suggest going that route of explicitly setting the Content-Length to 0.

Comment: Tried setting Content-Length header value to 0 and -1 but no luck.