# Remove HttpServletResponse header

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

The application I am working on works in a way where the request is sent from the browser to server A, server A makes some modifications to the request and forwards it to server B. Server B returns the response to server A which in turn returns it to the browser(Browser <=> Server A <=> Server B).

At server A I need to modify/remove a particular header "access-control-allow-origin" from the response given by server B. I can't do that at B where the response is created since I don't have access to the code. I need to do this at A itself.

I tried using the HttpServletResponseWrapper( [How do delete a HTTP response header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895196/how-do-delete-a-http-response-header) ) but I think it is useful only when the headers are not set already. In my case the headers are set and need to be modified/removed.

Comment: Do you have a webserver in front of server A ?

Comment: No. Server A itself is a webserver. Am I answering your question?

Comment: I mean, something like Apache where we can use mod_headers and remove the header

Comment: Server A is apache tomcat. I am not sure if this can be done using the servlet API.

Comment: Apache tomcat is a servlet container, I was asking about Apache Web Server. My bad Apache is ambiguous name :) Im replying with a possible solution

Comment: Please refer to the following answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7895292/957654).
Hope that helps.

Comment: The easiest way to handle this if you have control of the responding server is to add a response header for:

(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do delete a HTTP response header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895196/how-do-delete-a-http-response-header)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((org.apache.catalina.connector.Response)response).getCoyoteResponse()
    .getMimeHeaders()
    .removeHeader("access-control-allow-origin");
```

`getCoyoteResponse()` gets the underlying Response object which is where the headers are actually stored in a `MimeHeaders` object.  MimeHeaders has a convenient removeHeader method, among others.

Note that I didn't actually test this, but it looks like it should work.  Also, I found this in Tomcat 8.0.26 source, YMMV with a different version.

Comment: response is not accessible as it is private in ResponseFacade. Using reflexion is not a nice way to access that.