# I am getting null header value in spring security REST implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jersey, angular4-httpclient

I am using jersey , spring boot and spring security to create rest web service.
Which will be consumed by angular 2 client.

Client is sending authorization header in request , But on server i am not receiving any header value. I am using jersey for web service resource also using spring security authentication and authorization.

Kindly help.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailService; 

public SecurityConfiguration(CustomUserDetailsService userDetailService) {
     this.userDetailService  = userDetailService;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**")
    .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/app/**")
    .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/opas/Payment/**") ;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.cors();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/opas/common/**").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/opas/register/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                             
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD","GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH","OPTIONS"));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type","X-Requested-With"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

}

I am getting null header value in following code

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter { 

public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(authManager);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                HttpServletResponse res,
                                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }    

    try {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);       
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    catch (ExpiredJwtException eje) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage();
        responseMessage.setStatusCode(DomainConstants.FORBIDDEN_ERROR);
        responseMessage.setMessage(DomainConstants.SESSION_EXPIRED);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        res.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(responseMessage));
    }        
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request)throws ExpiredJwtException {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            if (user != null) {              
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());                  
            }
            return null;
        }        
    return null;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

in latest versions of spring, if your header value equal to `null`, you get `NullPointerException` in spring security. maybe for your case you need to remove it with `HttpServletResponseWrapper` like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895196)